# How can I check if the number of arguments passed into the shell script is exactly 2?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have some understanding that to check the number of arguments being passed into the shell script all I have to do inside the shell script is this: **Example 1**

```
if [ "$#" -ne 2 ]; then
   do something;
fi
```

However, I am a little confused and would like to know whether the name of the shell script when being run is considered part of the arguments as well as this is the case for python script when it comes to `sys.argv`.

An example in the terminal would be like:
**Example 2**

```
./script.sh $1 $2
```

In this case for **Example 2** how many arguments would actually be considered to be passed in to **Example 1** if else loop.

Comment: What result did you get when you tested it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of the script is not considered as part of the positional parameters.  This means that

```
somescript arg1 arg2
```

will set `$1` to `arg1` and `$2` to `arg2` and that `$#` will be `2`.

The name of the script will be available in `$0`, but `$0` is special in that it's *not* included in the array `$@`, and `$#` is the length (number of elements) of `$@`.